# How python simulates mouse clicks in inactive FlashActivex windows

Tags: python, winapi, flash, mouse, postmessage

I want to simulate mouse clicks in inactive window. But the click did not take effect.
The window levels are as follows

[image]

I want to send click events to inactive windows, So I chose `win32api.PostMessage` func.
It generates the following mouse events.(The red box shows normal mouse click events. The first two messages are sent by the code.)

[image]

But the code sending did not complete the click action, So I want to know what went wrong.
When the code is executing, I can see the shadow generated when the mouse is placed on the button.
In addition, I also verified that the mouse click position is correct.
But still failed to click the button.
I also tried to simulate the keyboard. It's normal.
so......I need help.

Here's what I do.
DEMO CODE:

```py
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import time

import win32api, win32gui, win32con


def click_minimize(hwnd, x, y):
    long_position = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)
    win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, long_position)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0000, long_position)


def flash_button_pos(child_hwnd):
    # Calculate mouse click position
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(child_hwnd)
    if (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1) < 1.4:
        length = x2 - x1
        hight = length / 1.4
        x = 0
        y = (y2 - y1 - hight) / 2
    else:
        hight = y2 - y1
        length = hight * 1.4
        x = (x2 - x1 - length) / 2
        y = 0
    x0 = int(0.171 * length + x)
    y0 = int(0.493 * hight + y)
    return x0, y0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hwld = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "MyGamePython")
    hwnd_child_list = []
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwld, lambda hWnd, param: param.append(hWnd), hwnd_child_list)
    child_hwnd = None
    for i in hwnd_child_list:
        if win32gui.GetClassName(i) == "MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX":
            child_hwnd = i
    x0, y0 = flash_button_pos(child_hwnd)
    print(x0, y0)
    click_minimize(child_hwnd, x0, y0)
```

If you need MyGamePython demo, please let me know. I can temporarily provide.
Thanks for your help!

See problem description for details.
Expect to point out the mistakes of my demo code.
Thanks!

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). I suggest you could try to use UI Automation.

Comment: My focus....,I hope that when the window is minimized, the simulated mouse click is still valid, In this case, UI Automation doesn't seem to be applicable. I'm not sure what the special case in < [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) > article is.  I tried to use PostMessage to simulate keyboard input. It is normal, but the effect of simulating mouse is not good. It is likely that I have not encountered the special case of simulating keyboard exceptions mentioned in the article.

Comment: In my opinion, if the Windows input behavior will be translated into a message(win-event), and the sys-action is driven by the event, the input behavior must be simulated through the message, only... there is no right way to send the message.(Just my personal understanding, not necessarily correct.)